# What are lifecycles of threads started from: Activity , UI less Fragment , Service (started, binded)?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, service

What are lifecycles of threads (f.i. consider a thread for playing music) started from:

- Activity
- UI less Fragment
- Service (started, binded)

When threads will be destroyed?
When to use Service and UI less Fragment for background tasks?

Comment: `Thread` does not have any lifecycle. You start one and then it just runs until it doesn't have anything to do anymore or until the OS kills it.

Comment: I mean exactly the case "until OS kills it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity => till android kills your process or the run method of your thread returns.

UI less Fragment => same as above.

Service started => till call to `stopSelf` or  `stopService` or the run method of your thread returns.

binded => till all client unbind from it or the run method of your thread returns.

> When to use Service and UI less Fragment for background tasks?

Service => long running operation regardless of having any UI.

UI less Fragment for background tasks => it is a design pattern to store your objects and preventing from creating another object (or in your context another thread) when activity is recreated. in this pattern you can access your thread reference regardless of activity is recreated or not. if for example you declare your thread in `onCreate` method, if you change the orientation 5 times you create 5 different threads, that may cause memory leak.

all above situation in one sentence is:

the thread runs till android kills the process or the thread returns from its run method.

Comment: yep, but Service has more high priority than Activity, so the subject is exactly what is difference to start threads from different android components. As I understand fragments have the same priority like activities.

Answer (score 0):

When threads will be destroyed?

From the documentation:

> When an application component starts and the application does not have any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux process for the application with a single thread of execution. By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and thread (called the "main" thread)
>
> ... However, you can arrange for different components in your application to run in separate processes, and you can create additional threads for any process.
>
> When an application is launched, the system creates a thread of execution for the application, called "main." This thread is very important because it is in charge of dispatching events to the appropriate user interface widgets, including drawing events.
>
> Because of the single thread model described above, it's vital to the responsiveness of your application's UI that you do not block the UI thread. If you have operations to perform that are not instantaneous, you should make sure to do them in separate threads ("background" or "worker" threads).

Anyway you should read the whole documentation [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).